# Displaying json data in ListView?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

In my android project, I have a `ListView` which populates the data entered by the user on runtime. Along with this, I want to show some data from an existing JSON file. So I parsed this JSON file and stored it in a `String`. How can I show both of these in my application?Can I use same the `Listview` for both ?

This is my code

```
 // Reading text file from assets folder
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try 
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                        "jsonshoutdata.txt")));
                String temp;
                while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(temp);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally 
            {
                try 
                {
                    br.close(); // stop reading
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            String myjsonstring = sb.toString();

            // Try to parse JSON
            try {
                //urlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Creating JSONObject from String
                JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);

                // Creating JSONArray from JSONObject
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("message");

                ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    // Creating JSONObject from JSONArray
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Getting data from individual JSONObject
                    String message = jsonObj.getString("msg");
                    messages.add(message);

                }
```

This is my customList adapter for json data

```
customtest adapter = new customtest(Single.this,R.layout.list_single_shout_single,messages); 
            ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_shout_screen);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
            {

                 @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(Single.this, "TEST.........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

        }
            catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my customList adapter which i already have

```
      final CustomListSingle adapter1 = new CustomListSingle(Single.this, web1,web,rounded,imageId2,imageId3,result1,result2);
             //CustomListSingle adapter = new CustomListSingle(Single.this, web1,web,rounded,imageId2,imageId3,result1,result2);
             list_shout_screen=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_shout_screen);
             list_shout_screen.setAdapter(adapter1);
             //list_shout_screen.setAdapter(adapter);
             list_shout_screen.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {
                  @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) 
                            {
                            TextView txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
                            txtTitle.length();
                            Toast.makeText(Single.this, "Length is " + txtTitle.getMeasuredWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            txtTitle.getTextSize();
                            }
                }
                );

             //Button click activity......

                final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
                final Button imb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
                imb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View arg0) 
                 { 
                    String str = et.getText().toString();
                      web1.add(str);
                      Toast.makeText(Single.this, "You entered...."+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      scrollMyListViewToBottom();
                      et.setText(" ");

                        }
```

This is my adapter class

```
public CustomListSingle(Activity context,ArrayList<String>  web,ArrayList<String> web1,Bitmap rounded,Integer[] imageId2,Integer[] imageId3,Bitmap image1,Bitmap image) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single_shout_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.web1 = web1;
        //this.imageId1 = imageId1; 

        this.rounded=rounded;
        this.imageId2 = imageId2;
        this.imageId3 = imageId3;
        this.image=image;
        this.image1=image1;

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single_shout_single, null, true);



    /*msg*/
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

    //pic
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            txtTitle.setLayoutParams(params);


    txtTitle.setText(web.get(position));

    txtTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test);





    imageView1.setImageBitmap(rounded); 


    imageView3.setImageBitmap(image1);


    return rowView;
    }

}
```

Method for making images circular

```
public static Bitmap getCircularBitmapFrom(Bitmap bitmap) 
        {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }
        float radius = bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight() ? ((float) bitmap
                .getHeight()) / 2f : ((float) bitmap.getWidth()) / 2f;
        if (radius < 0) {
            radius = 0;
        }
        Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(shader);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

        canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                radius, paint);

        return canvasBitmap;
    }
```

And this

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.white);
        Bitmap bmp1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.prof_pic_a);
        Bitmap images =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources
               (),R.drawable.prof_pic_a); 
        Bitmap rounded;

         rounded=getCircularBitmapFrom(images);
         result1=getCircularBitmapFrom(bmp);
         result2=getCircularBitmapFrom(bmp1);
```

Comment: I usually make a `JSONArray` out of the `String` and then extract `JSONObject`s from it.

Comment: Ya you can use same ListView to display both the data. Try adding both the data to the same ArrayList and use this array to your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have this arraylist

```
 ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();   //add this line on top so it will be accessed globally
```

and your button code

```
final Button imb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            imb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) 
             { 
                String str = et.getText().toString();
                  messages.add(str);
                  Toast.makeText(Single.this, "You entered...."+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  scrollMyListViewToBottom();
                  et.setText(" ");


                  adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();  //list is the name of your listview


                    }
```

call `notifyDataSetChanged` whenever you want to update your `listview`(after adding data in your arraylist)

Comment: Could u help me please ??

Comment: Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830251/refreshing-screen-which-uses-json-in-android